# Adding model attribute to spring MockMvc call

Tags: spring, testing, mockmvc, modelattribute

I'm writing a test for a simple controller.

The controller checks if the modelattribute "ADDED_OBJECT" exists and returns a success page and an error page when the modelattribute is missing.
Testing the error path is no problem but I don't know how to trigger the success path, which is usually executed after a succesfull POST (Post/Redirect/Get) pattern.
Is it possible to add the modelattribute to the mockMvc call?

Controller:

```
@GetMapping("/added")
public String addedContract(Model model) {
    if (!model.containsAttribute(ADDED_OBJECT)) {
        return ERROR_400;
    }
    return "added";
}
```

Test:

```
@Test
public void added() throws Exception {
    mockMvc.perform(get("/added"))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(content().string(not(containsString("400"))));
}
```

Thanks

Comment: check my answer here. Eventhough the question is different, the solution is the same  
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48156808/how-to-test-spring-rest-controller-with-mockito-when-if-controller-has-httpservl/48157132#48157132

Comment: I think I understand what you mean. But I cannot get it to work when trying like this:

 Model mockModel = mock(Model.class);
    when(mockModel.containsAttribute(ADDED_OBJECT)).thenReturn(true);

Comment: what error are you getting

Comment: the model ist just empty

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to set flashAttribute like this

```
 mockMvc.perform(get("/added").flashAttr("ADDED_OBJECT", "SomeObject"))
```

This way you can control what gets passed to model object in controller and accordingly design your tests for various use cases.

Comment: This works thank you!
I tried param, requestattr and sessionattr but not flashAttr ...